# Is it unsafe to get a AES Key from AndroidKeyStore without a password?

Tags: android, security, kotlin, keystore, android-keystore

I am creating a small Android app (API > 23) and have to do without a login screen. Nevertheless, the user's data should be encrypted, for this I generate or load an AES key from the AndroidKeyStore:

```
fun generateSymmetricKey(keyAlias: String): Key {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore.load(null)
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(keyAlias)) {
            val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
            val keyGenParameterSpec =
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    keyAlias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                    .build()
            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
            return keyGenerator.generateKey()
        }
        return keyStore.getKey(keyAlias,null)
    }
```

With the method getKey I load the stored key from the Keystore without a given password. The question arose if this makes the KeyStore unsafe. Or whether Android itself sets a password for this KeyStore when creating the APK.

Answer (score 0):

As to my knowledge, only the same App has access to its KeyStore objects. So in theory, you should be safe.

Please keep in mind however, that when the user has your app installed in some kind of parallel space (e.g. Parallels), each app within this space is the same app from an operating system perspective. Therefore, those apps would have access to your KeyStore entry as well.